# echo "$myvar" | awk 'FNR ....' doesn't echo anything

Tags: linux, bash, variables, ssh, awk

I'm ssh'ing to a list of machines and getting all of their system info (model, hardware address, etc.)

The info I get back comes nice and neatly organized to easily use awk to grab the info I need.  However, what doesn't work, is FNR to select a specific row:

```
entry=$(tssh -n 10 $host 'smbios-sys-info')
echo "$entry" | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3 $4}'
```

If I remove the FNR, awk '{print $3 $4}' alone works just fine, but gives me field's 3 and 4 of all rows instead of the one row I want.

If I do this outside of the script in the shell, this works:

```
smbios-sys-info | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3 $4}'
```

I imagine that there might be some underlying implications regarding the use of echo "$entry" (variable in quotes) that somehow affect awk's ability to select a specific row, even though "$entry" preserves the format of smbios-sys-info.

Just to give you an idea, here is what the command smbios-sys-info outputs:

```
[root@host ~]# smbios-sys-info
Libsmbios version:      2.2.26
Product Name:           OptiPlex 760
Vendor:                 Dell Inc.
BIOS Version:           A02
System ID:              123456
Service Tag:            ABCDEFG
Express Service Code:   11111111111
Asset Tag:              N/A
Property Ownership Tag: N/A
```

EDIT I realize an alternative is that I can probably use awk in the ssh command to grab one field instead of all fields.  But that's no good for my situation because I need to do multiple stuff with the system info, so it's easier to grab the whole thing in one shot and then work with it locally.

Comment: And what about `awk`ing in the `tssh` command?

Comment: Haha, yeah, as soon as I posted that, I thought, "someone's going to suggest that..." so I added an edit about it :)

Comment: `doesn't work` means? no output? or with error msg? btw, `echo "$entry"` outputs correct format?

Comment: Ooops I did not see the edit. My fault!

Comment: There is no output when piped to awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3 $4}'.  And echo "$entry" (variable wrapped in quotes) outputs the exact same thing as smbios-sys-info, with new lines and spacing format preserved.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt can you try to pipe echo output to `awk '{print FNR, $0}'`? what's the output? and btw, you could consider to use `NR` instead of `FNR`

Comment: echo "$entry" | awk '{print FNR, $0}' prints the same as echo "$entry" (i.e. the output appears in the correct format with new lines and spacing)

Comment: @CptSupermrkt did you try changing FNR->NR in your original line? worked for you?

Comment: @Kent Hah!  For whatever reason, NR works!  Thanks for that suggestion! (I didn't even know about NR).  Make an answer so I can properly give you credit.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt just curious, can you report your awk version pls?

Comment: I'm on SunOS 5.10, and awk exists with a man page, but awk -v, awk -V, awk -version, awk -Version, awk --v, and so on and so on doesn't give me the version.  "man awk | grep -i version" has zero results as well.  Someone online with a similar problem was able to determine that they are using "old" awk based on "awk 1 /dev/null" --- "new" awk exits silently, "old" awk gives errors.  Mine gives errors.  *shrugs* lol

Comment: @CptSupermrkt `awk --version` should work :D but if you didn't install gawk, yours maybe posix awk. do you have `nawk` on your sunbox? try `nawk` with your `FNR==2`

Comment: Hmm, yup, nawk works with FNR.  Weird.  Oh well, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FNR         The input record number in the current input file.
>
> NR          The total number of input records seen so far.

here,  with my awk (Gnu awk 4.1.0), both NR and FNR worked. but if you don't have a file as input, better use NR.

**@rici**
The problem is that really old awk's don't implement FNR as a special variable; only NR.